# Style a Multidimencional Array by main and submain

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following "problem"... after a few hrs scratching my head I can't figure it out..
So here we go... I have use array's before, but just a simple array's

```
$arr = array('1', '2', '3',[...]);
```

I can manage to deal with that kind of array, and just a few days ago I started to learn multidimensional array's ... which they should be called, Multidimensional Nightmare... any way, I had a multidimensional array ordered by "name" from the SQL... any way... that array needed to be organize and thank you to a user named Edakos here in stackoverflow my array got organize by main cat with it's sub-cats...
and my array now looks like this...

```
 Array
(
    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 10
            [category_name] => Main Category
            [category_parent_id] => 0
            [category_child_id] => 10
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [196] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category_id] => 196
                            [category_name] => Sub Category 1
                            [category_parent_id] => 10
                            [category_child_id] => 196
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
                    [198] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [category_id] => 196
                            [category_name] => Sub Category 2
                            [category_parent_id] => 10
                            [category_child_id] => 198
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
    [.....]
);
```

And now here is my attempt to style this array...

```
foreach($tree as $cats => $info){
     echo '<span> ID: ' . $cats . '</span><br>';
        foreach($info as $k => $v){
            echo '<span style="margin-left:10px; color:red;">' . $v ['category_name'] . ' </span><br>';
        }
}
```

// the $tree contain the full array that is show above...

and now the result is something like

```
ID: 10
1
M
0
1

ID: 1
1
M
0
1
```

Where ID: is the id # for the main category that is ok ... and the data is the data for the main category such is, ID, name,parent id, child id which is the main cat id...

array looks like this

```
[10] => stdClass Object
            (
                [category_id] => 10
                [category_name] => Main Category
                [category_parent_id] => 0
                [category_child_id] => 10
                [children] => Array
                    (....
```

so as I understand is [KEY] => ARRAY ( key=>val, key=>val... and son... until the key children which contain the sub category in an array...

So, as I wrote in my code:

```
foreach($info as $k => $v){
echo '<span style="margin-left:10px; color:red;">' . $v ['category_name'] . ' </span><br>';
            }
```

I should be able to just get the name for that first array which is my main category in this case "Main Category"... but instead I only get the letter M... **and there is where I got lost...** so anyway... the following should be to get the subcategories... for that I have this...

```
    foreach($info as $k => $v){
    echo '<span style="margin-left:10px; color:red;">' . $v ['category_name'] . ' </span>
         foreach ($k[children] as $sk => $sv){
    echo '<span style="margin-left:10px; color:green;">' . $sv ['category_name'] . ' </span>

}
<br>';
}
```

and with that I got nothing...

finally the idea is to get the following

```
Main cat 1
   |_Sub Cat 2
   |_Sub Cat 4
   |_Sub Cat 6
Main Cat 2
   |_Sub Name 2
   |_Sub Names 3
[... and son ] ...
```

I have to note that this are my first attempts to work with multidimensional array, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read this **multidimensional nightmare**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you iterate the main array and then you iterate the children object-array. You're dealing with objects here, so the notation is $object->variablename instead of $array['variablename'].

```
foreach ( $tree as $cats => info){
    echo '<span> cat: ' . $info->category_name. '</span><br>';

    foreach ($info->children as $child){
        echo '<span>' . $child->category_name . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarified that now I understand it... and thank you for the example